# Perl: Regular expressions Pattern matching

Tags: regex, perl

Is `[A]` a regular expression that will match a string of characters which contains any number of occurrences of the letter A (and only the letter A, with no other characters or spaces) such as `AAAA`?

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: I am not asking for you to do my homework i am asking for help . I don't understand at all i need some guidance. I put the question there for someone to understand what i am asking

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: $string =~[A]  this is what I have so far. Im not getting any where is this the correct format or should it be different

Comment: Well, for starters, it would help to know what's a regular expression. You're writing Perl code (kinda) instead of a regular expression. The regular expression is what you'd replace `...` with in `$string =~ /.../`

Comment: Hint: The answer isn't `A` or `[A]` because while those match `AAAA` (as they should), they also match `ZAZ` (when they shouldn't).

Comment: ok thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Anything in square brackets is a [*character class*](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html). This is complicated enough that it has its own Perl documentation page (in the link), so it's not a surprise it wasn't evident how it works.

A character class defines a *set* of possible characters; when pattern matching, a character class by itself matches *one* character from the input, no matter how many characters there are inside the square brackets.

```
/[A]/     # find one copy of 'A' anywhere in the string
/[abcd]/  # find one copy of any of 'a', 'b', 'c', or 'd' anywhere in the string
/[A..Z]/  # find any one uppercase ASCII character somewhere in the string
```

If you want your class to match differently, you can add modifiers:

```
/[A..Z]+/ # find one or more uppercase ASCII characters in a row
/[A]*/    # find zero or more 'A's in a row
```

The linked page will show you a lot of other options to specify sets of characters inside the square brackets. But the key is that one set of square brackets matches one character unless you add `+` (one or more of these) or '*' (zero or more of these).

Answer (score 0):

No.

The regular expression pattern `[A]` can be simplified to just `A`. It will match any string that contains `A`. While that includes `AAAA`, it also includes `ZAZ`.

For starters, you will need to anchor the match.